# Android BindingAdapter not called when value is updated

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata

One `Activity`, two `Fragment`s that share a common `ViewModel`. I have verified that the view model reference is the same in each fragment.

In the layout XML for fragment one, there is a `TextInputLayout`. Fragment two updates the view model with a boolean value. The text input layout is observing this value and should call a `BindingAdapter` when the value is changed.

The binding adapter fires when the fragments are instantiated and their layouts are inflated, so I know that the view is observing this value. However, later on, when fragment two updates the value, the view in fragment one does not trigger the binding adapter.

This is in `onCreateView()` of fragment one:

```
registrationViewModel = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders
                .of(this, RegistrationViewModelFactory(prefs, dataFetcherService))
                .get(RegistrationViewModel::class.java)
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
```

and this is the view that is observing that view model:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/reg_auth_code_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
bind:errorState="@{registrationViewModel.registrationData.authorizationError}"
                bind:errorMessage="@{@string/invalid_auth_code}">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/reg_auth_code"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@{registrationViewModel.registrationData.authCode}"
                    android:hint="@string/enter_auth_code"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

As for fragment two, same code in onCreateView():

```
registrationViewModel = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders
                .of(this, RegistrationViewModelFactory(prefs, dataFetcherService))
                .get(RegistrationViewModel::class.java)
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
```

When a button is clicked, fragment two fires an activity in the view model:

```
private fun attemptNavigationToUserData() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        isAuthorized = runBlocking { useCase.isAuthorized() }
        registrationData.value?.authorizationError = !isAuthorized
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("errorState", "errorMessage")
fun setErrorState(
    textInputLayout: TextInputLayout?,
    errorState: Boolean,
    errorMessage: String) {

    textInputLayout?.let {
        it.isErrorEnabled = errorState
        if (errorState) it.error = errorMessage
    }
}
```

This all seems to be set up correctly, AFAIK. As I mentioned, the binding adapter fires when the views are initially inflated, but never again.

Why isn't my XML observing the view model? Or, why isn't the binding adapter firing upon update??

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is most likely that you don't set the lifecycleOwner for your fragment binding object.
For further information see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56011798/1894338

Comment: I do set the lifecycle owner.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate, I spent nearly an hour to find the reason why the layout wasn't being updated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66488334/9747826

setLifeCyclerOwner and setting the viewModel are the key.

Answer (score 0):

You `authorizationError` should be a `LiveData<>`.So that the BindingAdapter mothod will called automatically when the LiveData's value(`errorState`) is updated.
If you want BindingAdapter method receive the automatic update, you should use LiveData in the dataBinding expression.
Such as:

```
subTitleText="@{removableItemsViewModel.removableItemsInfo}"
```

and the BindingAdapter method and the LiveData:

```
val removableItemsInfo: LiveData<Pair<Int, Long>>
-----------------------------------------------------
@BindingAdapter("subTitleText")
fun setSubTitleText(textView: TextView, pair: Pair<Int, Long>){
}
```

also,don't forget to invoke `binding.setLifecycleOwner()`